# remembering dynamically added input elements and their values

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, dynamic, file-upload

I have a page creation wizard that I am building and I am allowing the user to add up to 3 images to the page. The code I am currently using gets the job done, but it is not working like I want it to. On my page wizard this is the html that contains the file inputs:

```
<div class="pictures">
    <label>Add Pictures </label><span>(Maximum: 3)</span>
    <span id="input_container"></span>
    <a href="javascript:addPic()">add</a> |
    <a href="javascript:rmvPic()">remove</a>
</div>
```

and my javascript looks like this:

```
var picNum = 0;

function addPic() {
    if (picNum < 3) { picNum++;
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
        input.setAttribute('name', 'picture_' + picNum);
        input.setAttribute('id', 'picture_' + picNum);

        var container = document.getElementById('input_container');
        container.appendChild(input);
    }
}

function rmvPic() {
    if (picNum > 0) {
        var container = document.getElementById('input_container');
        container.removeChild(document.getElementById('picture_' + picNum));
        picNum--;
    }
}
```

This current setup allows the user to dynamically add the amount of images they want to their page, but after they submit the form and go back to edit the page, all of the elements they added are now removed from the page. I would like it so when the user comes back and wants to change the image(s), the wizard will remember the amount of pictures they added, and the values they had.

I don't know if what I am saying makes sense, so if you need more information I would willingly provide it. And I am working with ruby on rails if you need to know that.

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'go back to the edit page' I'm assuming you mean that a page load occurs.  If that's the case then you lose the state (javascript vars will be reset) of the submitted page where the images were added.  If you performed a submit than the values you're looking for should exist on the server.  So, when reloading the edit page you'll need to request the values from the server(ajax) or render them in the page scope.

I don't clearly understand how your navigating between pages or how your storing the submitted values so I'm going off quite a few assumptions here.

In short, HTML is stateless so you need a way to store your values in between pages.  You can either store on the server or store locally(in a cookie or local cache).

Without a clearer view of how your app is structured I can't recommend an approach.